# Make Play! recompile when a file is modified rather than when browser is refreshed

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Just starting out with the Play framework and one minor irritant is that it takes a long time (a few seconds) for it to recompile when I make a change then refresh so I can see it in the browser. This can get a bit irritating when making many minor adjustments to a view, for example.

Is there a magic way to make Play attempt to recompile whenever a source file is changed rather than waiting until the browser is refreshed?

Comment: Why did you answer your own question within a minute of asking it?

Comment: @ianNewson Well, I had the question, couldn't find an answer here, then worked it out for myself - but thought the answer would be useful for others.

Comment: @IanNewson See this StackExchange blog by jeff Atwood -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. Answering your own question for a piece of knowledge that is not present on SO is actively encouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The Play console is based on SBT, which has a handy way to run a command whenever a source file is changed by prefixing it with a tilde. So prefix `run` with a tilde like this in the Play console:

```
[my-play-app] $ ~run
```

And the application will attempt to recompile whenever a source file is changed, saving you precious seconds that soon start to add up.

Comment: You can just run it directly from command line without running console first: `play ~run`

Comment: how to stop application running with `~run`? Ctrl+D or Ctrl+C not working